# AIDA64 monitores only HDD temperature

Tags: laptop, cpu, temperature

I installed AIDA64 extreme edition on my laptop to monitor laptop CPU temperature, but, surprisingly, there are no other temperatures but HDD's temperature.

I checked bios for some settings, but my version of bios has very few of them listed and no settings to configure temperatures setttings at all.

Laptop model: Lenovo G50-70.

Is there a way to enable temperatures monitoring?

Comment: Have you tried another program?  If you do try another program, and that program reports no other temperatures, its safe to say there are no other temperature sensors.

Comment: Try [speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php)

Comment: I tried another software (specifically CPUTemp) and it shows CPU temp normally. What can be the reason that AIDA64 rejects to display other temps?